# 1 PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.6

Error when running :

> php artisan migrate:reset

in the root of my Laravel site:

```
  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because
 the target machine actively refused it.
")
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", "homes
tead", "secret", [])
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

When i ran the -v i got this:

```
  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because
 the target machine actively refused it.
")
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", "homes
tead", "secret", [])
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 68

  3   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createPdoConnection("mysql:host=
127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", "homestead", "secret", [])
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php : 44

  4   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector::createConnection("mysql:host=127
.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=homestead", [])
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector.php : 24

  5   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector::connect()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory.php : 183

  6   Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory::Illuminate\Database\Conn
ectors\{closure}()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 915

  7   call_user_func(Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 915

  8   Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdo()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 940

  9   Illuminate\Database\Connection::getReadPdo()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 399

  10  Illuminate\Database\Connection::getPdoForSelect()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 325

  11  Illuminate\Database\Connection::Illuminate\Database\{closure}("select * fr
om information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?")
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 657

  12  Illuminate\Database\Connection::runQueryCallback("select * from informatio
n_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?", Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 624

  13  Illuminate\Database\Connection::run("select * from information_schema.tabl
es where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?", Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Connection.php : 333

  14  Illuminate\Database\Connection::select("select * from information_schema.t
ables where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?")
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder.php : 18

  15  Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::hasTable("migrations")
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository.php : 169

  16  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\DatabaseMigrationRepository::repositoryExis
ts()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php : 545

  17  Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::repositoryExists()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Database\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand.php : 63

  18  Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand::handle()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 29

  19  call_user_func_array([])
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 29

  20  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 87

  21  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Founda
tion\Application), Object(Closure))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Container\BoundMethod.php : 31

  22  Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Applic
ation), [])
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Container\Container.php : 564

  23  Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Console\Command.php : 183

  24  Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input
\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Co
mmand.php : 252

  25  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Co
nsole\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Console\Command.php : 170

  26  Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Arg
vInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\symfony\console\Applicatio
n.php : 865

  27  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Data
base\Console\Migrations\ResetCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Ar
gvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\symfony\console\Applicatio
n.php : 241

  28  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Cons
ole\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\symfony\console\Applicatio
n.php : 143

  29  Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Consol
e\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Console\Application.php : 88

  30  Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input
\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illu
minate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php : 121

  31  Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Cons
ole\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      C:\Users\jarro\Documents\Sites\homestead\artisan : 37
```

I think i know what is going on. I have had to change my database connection to 192.168.10.10 in PHPStorm to connect to MySQL because the MySQL is on the homestead VM (virtual machine) and i cant connect to it locally because technically its on a "Different Machine". So then i went looking for where to change database info. My queries work as of now. So i don't know why this is having issues. I found the /config/database.php and changed every username, password, db name, host to the correct things :

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.10.10'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],

'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.10.10'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],

'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '192.168.10.10'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

But this, didn't really help. I did the command

> vagrant reload --provision

to make sure that wasn't an issue. It is saying in the error message in the terminal

> 2
>   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=**127.0.0.1**;port=3306;dbname=homestead",
>   "homes tead", "secret", [])

---

> 127.0.0.1

---

When i clearly changed the host in the database.php file in the /config to 192.168.10.10, which works when trying to connect with phpstorm.

I am having a hard time learning laravel and i am confused on how to get this changed to 192.168.10.10. Can an experienced person or at least anyone try to tell me the right direction to help me find the variable $dsn to change the host being passed in it?

**Any help is appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running
`php artisan cache:clear` or 
`php artisan config:clear`

You might also have a .env file overriding it possibly.

Comment: Where is the .env file? i seen that on some SOF posts but couldn't find that file. Where is it located?

Comment: You are correct, the .env file was overriding the other info. :D thanks for your help. I found it in the root of the site folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try edit your .env file in your root folder or .env.example file also in your root folder